# Android: Orientation on fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I have a menu with fragments instead of activities. Each fragment is full screen when is called. I want to be able to make for fragment1 - orientation portrait, fragment 2 - orientation landscape etc..
For activities is easy beacuse i can change them in the manifest, but how can i do on fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `onCreate` of each `fragment` you have to call

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(requestedOrientation)
```

that's will set the orientation of your `Activity` (se the `Fragment` orientation) to `requestedOrientation`. This is the only way. Fragment itself can not manage its orientation